How can I set up containers in a kubernetes pod to not need any SELinux-relabelling of a shared volume?
I have a kubernetes pod with two containers, one of which is a sidecar container and is priveleged, the other of which is not priveleged. The sidecar container mounts a FUSE filesystem within a shared emptyDir volume. The main container mounts the same emptyDir volume and wants to read and write files within the FUSE filesystem provided by the sidecar.
To make this work, the sidecar container has mountPropagation: Bidirectional on its volumeMount so that the filesystem it mounts gets propagated to other containers. The main container has mountPropagation: HostToContainer so that it gets the FUSE filesystem provided by the sidecar.
When I do this, kubelet tries to relabel the SELinux labels on the emptyDir volume, which causes it to try to walk recursively through the FUSE filesystem, which causes an error somewhere, probably because the FUSE filesystem doesn't support some operation that relabeling requires. The exact error, which appears as an event on the pod is:
Error: relabel failed /var/lib/kubelet/pods/54f3b149-4c33-4d78-8c60-e4cecdf188ea/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/workspace: open /var/lib/kubelet/pods/54f3b149-4c33-4d78-8c60-e4cecdf188ea/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/workspace/src/path/to/something: no such file or directory

I have a hard requirement to avoid recursing through my FUSE filesystem, because doing so will take too long. Is there a way that I can set the SELinux label of my sidecar and main containers in such a way that relabeling isn't necessary? I'm aware of securityContext.seLinuxOptions.level in the pod spec but I don't know what I should set it to in this case.
Or perhaps when I mount the FUSE filesystem there is some kind of SELinux configuration that I should apply so that, even though it is being mounted by a process in a priveleged container, it will not trigger relabeling by kubelet when mounted in a non-priveleged container?
The pod spec is as follows:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <app>
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: workspace
        emptyDir:
          sizeLimit: 500Mi

      initContainers:
      - name: sidecar
        image: <sidecar image mounts a FUSE filesystem at /workspace/src>
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /workspace
          name: workspace
          mountPropagation: Bidirectional
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          capabilities:
            add: ["CAP_SYS_ADMIN"]  # for fuse

      containers:
      - name: main
        image: <main image reads and writes to /workspace/src>
        workingDir: /workspace/src
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /workspace
          name: workspace
          mountPropagation: HostToContainer


